# Cant't triple des encrypt strings that less than 1376 character

Tags: php, phpseclib, 3des, tripledes

I have a problem about 3DES algorithm when i have work on php ( phpseclib ).
If my string length shortest 1376 or 1300 Triple DES on the phpseclib , Triple DES don't work and can't encrypt my string !!!

How many must length my string that this algorithm working?

Use phpseclib package for encryption.

code :

```
$key = '';
$cipher = new \phpseclib\Crypt\TripleDES(\phpseclib\Crypt\DES::MODE_CBC);

//my key is hex format
$cipher->setKey(hex2bin($key));
$cipher->setIV(hex2bin('0000000000000000'));

//my data is hex format

$plaintext = hex2bin($data);

echo $cipher->encrypt($plaintext);
```

tank you.

Comment: Hi, please include [your code / what you have tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @CharonX code assigned to question

Comment: Your code works just fine for me: https://pastebin.com/VwYLmaHn

Answer (score -1):

I can solve this problem.

in the php you must paded string to 16 character !!!

such as :

```
str_pad($input, 16, "your padded char", STR_PAD_LEFT); // or STR_PAD_RIGHT for padded from right
```

Comment: That is not at all true. phpseclib uses PKCS1 padding unless you've explicitly disabled padding.